# oData server with nodejs, jaydata and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, jaydata

I'm using Ubuntu Server 12.04, node v0.8.14 and jaydata v1.2.3 and trying to install a node odata server as per this post : http://jaydata.org/blog/install-your-own-odata-server-with-nodejs-and-mongodb

On node REPL when the instruction require('jaydata'); is executed it returns Should be empty: []

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is output from the Q promise library and does no harm - albeit annoying. :) But Q is so cool otherwise so we just accept it's courtesy console.log output.